# Pandas renaming multiple NaN column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When reading csv file my dataframe has these column names:

`df.columns`:

`Index([nan,"A", nan, "B", "C", nan],dtype='object')`

For unknown reasons it does not automatically name them as `"Unnamed:0"` and so on as it usually does.

Therefore is it possible to rename the multiple `nan` columns to Unnamed:0, Unnamed:1 and so on, depending on how many `nan` columns are there- the number of `nan` columns varies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first convert your columns to a `series` then apply a cumulative count `cumcount` to a boolean condition which is True if there is a null occurrence. then use the conditional value to fill the null values.

```
s = pd.Series(df.columns)

print(s)


0    NaN
1      A
2    NaN
3      B
4      C
5    NaN


s = s.fillna('unnamed:' + (s.groupby(s.isnull()).cumcount() + 1).astype(str))

print(s)

0    unnamed:1
1            A
2    unnamed:2
3            B
4            C
5    unnamed:3
dtype: object


df.columns = s
```